# Altium testpoints auto-placement

Tags: altium, autorouter, test-point

Is there a way to use Altium to automatically generate test points on an already routed board? When there is no usable via, I'd like to place a pad on the net.

When reviewing Altium API reference documentation, especially for the [IPCB_TestPointStyleRule](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/SCRT/PCB+API+Design+Objects+Interfaces#IPCB_TestPointUsage%20rule) object, I see this statement :

> The auto-router includes a test point generator, which can identify existing pads and vias as test points, as well as adding test point pads to nets which cannot be accessed at existing pads and vias.

This sounds super promising, but looking at the auto-router, I see nothing that refers to test points placement. I assume that the net would need to be routed by the autorouter to get a testpoint added.

Anything I could use? I am considering scripting the feature, which I'd like to avoid.  I found a script on GitHub that creates the test points but does not place them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to generate the testpoints, but you will need to move them manually to the right place

https://github.com/Altium-Designer-addons/scripts-libraries/tree/master/TestpointMaker

Comment: I did find that script myself and already had mentionned it in my question. But thanks